# How to prove the following

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random-matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n} (n\ge p)$ be a positive definite symmetric matrix having a Wishart distribution with mean $\mathbf{0}$ and covariance $\boldsymbol\Sigma\otimes \mathbf{I}$. Let the eigenvalue-eigenvector pair of $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ be written as
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol\Sigma\Gamma = \Gamma\Delta
\end{equation} 
where, $\Gamma$ is the eigenvector matrix and $\Delta$ is the eigenvalue matrix with diagonal entries $\left(\delta_1,\cdots,\delta_p\right)$. Now, let $\mathbf{U} = \sqrt{n}\left(\Gamma'\mathbf{A}\Gamma-n\Delta\right)$. One can see that the mean of $\mathbf{U}$ is $\mathbf{0}$.

How to prove the following
\begin{equation}
\text{E}\left[u_{ij}u_{gh}\right] = \delta_i\delta_j\left(\delta_{ih}\delta_{jg} + \delta_{ig}\delta_{jh}\right)
\end{equation} 
where, $\text{E}$ indicates expected value.

The following equation will be handy in finding the above expectation:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{AA}^T\\
\text{cov}\left(\text{vec }\mathbf{S}\right) = n\left(\mathbf{I}+K_p\right)\left(\boldsymbol\Sigma\otimes\boldsymbol\Sigma\right)
\end{equation} 
where, $\mathbf{K}_p$ is a commutation matrix of size $p^2\times p^2$ and $\mathbf{I}$ is an identity matrix of same size. where $\left(\text{vec }\mathbf{S}\right)$ indicates that the columns of $\mathbf{S}$ have been stacked on top of each other forming a vector.

Comment: What is delta with double subscripts? From your explanation of your notation you only refer to single subscripted delta.

Comment: Forgot to mention. $\delta$ with single subscript is the eigenvalue while with double subscript is kronecker delta function

Comment: Makes sense. You also mention that the covariance of A is something (in the beginning), and then later on that E(AA') (which is the covariance in this case) is something else. Are these expressions correct? I suspect that the final expression should be E(UU')?

Comment: Corrected the mistake. Thanks for pointing out. "cov" indicates covariance.